# Can __restrict__ be applied to shared_ptr<T>?

Tags: c++, g++, clang, shared-ptr, restrict-qualifier

Smart pointers are pointers underneath, so is there any way of defining a `shared_ptr` parameter to a function as not aliasing another `shared_ptr`, or another pointer of any sort?

Or is this, for some reason, unnecessary?

I'm concerned with the gcc >=4.2 and llvm-clang >=2.0 compilers (answers for other compilers would also be  interesting).

Comment: C++ doesn't have any `restrict` or `__restrict__` keyword.  If you're asking about language extensions in a particular compiler, you need to say which.

Comment: @BenVoigt sorry - clarified in edit.

Comment: It seems unlikely that a finction wanting to work on restricted pointers wants to claim shared ownership of the pointer. Not to mention that in a system with shared ownership you end up knowing that the pointers are indeed distinct. In any case, I'd guess your function actualky wants to take [restricted] pointers rather than `std::shared_ptr<T>`s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just extract the pointers with `.get()` and mark them as `__restrict__`. Remember, putting `__restrict__` into the function parameters is the same as putting `__restrict__` on local variables. In particular, the compiler doesn't attempt to stop you from calling the function with two pointers that obviously point to the same object; e.g. `foo(i,i)`.

If you want to make a promise to the compiler that certain pointers don't reference each other, allowing the compiler to do more optimizations, then use this code below and do your operations through `xp` and `yp` instead of `x` and `y`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

void foo(shared_ptr<int> x, shared_ptr<int> y) {
        int * __restrict__ xp = x.get();
        int * __restrict__ yp = y.get();
}

int main() {
        shared_ptr<int> i = make_shared<int>(3);
        shared_ptr<int> j = make_sharet<int>(4);
        foo(i,j);
}
```

Comment: Why do you say that marking function parameters as `restrict` is different to declaring local `restrict` pointer variables? Is that something to do with `gcc` optimisation or is it an underlying behaviour of `restrict` (that I don't currently understand ;) )

Comment: I say it's *not* different. I'll try to reword it to be more clear.

Comment: I was going to write this, but I couldn't find ANY grammar for `__restrict__` that said whether it was allowed on local variables.  Is there documentation somewhere?

Comment: @BenVoigt `restrict` is defined as a *type-qualifier* just like `const` and `volatile` (C99 §6.7.3/1). `__restrict__` is a GCC extension and might not be precisely defined by any formal grammar, even if one exists.

Comment: agreed, @BenVoigt ! Edited so they don't alias. I think I was intending to talk about that in the answer, but I forgot and left this error without discussing it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to perform non-aliased operations on the underlying object associated with a shared pointer you could explicitly delegate to a worker routine that takes a non-aliased pointer parameter:

```
void worker (mytype *__restrict x, mytype *__restrict y)
{
    // do something with x, y with a no-alias guarantee
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<mytype> p(new mytype);
    std::shared_ptr<mytype> q(new mytype);

// explicitly delegate the shared object
    worker(p.get(), q.get());

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what you have in mind, but this would allow the high-level memory management to be dealt with safely by the smart pointer, while doing the low level work *possibly* more efficiently with no-alias pointers.

As @BenVoigt pointed out, `restrict` is only offically part of `c99` - `c++` isn't supposed to know anything about it. `MSVC` supports it anyway via `__restrict` and as you've said `GCC` has `__restrict__`.

Hope this helps.